# Mysql / Multi delete statement - #Cannot delete or update a parent row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I try to create procedure to delete category and connections between them but unfortunately i don`t know how to deal with my relation.

```
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`saver`.`categorytree`, CONSTRAINT `categorytree_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`))
```

here is code I created:

```
delete con, cc from categorytree con 
join categorytree ct on con.child_id = ct.child_id
join category cc on con.child_id = cc.id
where con.parent_id = 1
```

Tables:

```
create table category (
id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar (50) not null,
primary key(id) 
);


create table categorytree(
parent_id int not null,
child_id int not null ,
depth int,
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) references category(id),
FOREIGN KEY (child_id) references category(id)
);
```

[image: For select.]
Can someone help?

edit:

`ON DELETE CASCADE` do job for me. thanks.

```
create table categorytree(
parent_id int not null,
child_id int not null ,
depth int,
FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) references category(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (child_id) references category(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want to join the same table here... `categorytree con 
join categorytree ct on con.child_id = ct.child_id` What is the need for this join ?

Comment: to select all tree of categories connection

Comment: and to bypass the cursor

Comment: A simple `delete con, cc from categorytree con 
join category cc on con.child_id = cc.id
where con.parent_id = 1` won't do the job?

Comment: that works fine if i want delete connections but after while i added category table to my statement that`s throws me an error. I think this want to delete my category before all connections are delete.

Comment: see my edit i added prt scrn. I any way to do delete DESC?

Comment: `categorytree con join categorytree ct on con.child_id = ct.child_id` is nesesery any way.

Comment: What happens if you specify `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the foreign key ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV thanks, this let query to run. `3 rows affected. (Query took 0.0602 seconds.)`

Answer (score 0):

you use recursive function for delete or update

```js
// Function to build hierarchy tree
function hierarchy($array, $parent = 0, $level = 0) {
    $tree = '<ul>';
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        if ($v['parent'] === NULL) $v['parent'] = 0;
        if ($v['parent'] === $parent) {
            $tree .= '<li>';
            $tree .= $v['name'];
            $tree .= hierarchy($array, $v['id'], $level+1);
            $tree .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    $tree .= '</ul>';
    return $tree;
}
```

link: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/building-multi-level-menu-dynamically-with-pdo-in-php/298325/2